# Mongoose Schema. How to create default value for a object of object?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Meet my UserModel:

```
var UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', 
{
    username: { type: String, default: 'Nameless'},
    password: String,
    registry: String,
});
```

I want to do something like this to my username key:

```
username: { 
  description: {type: String, default: 'Name'},
  value: {type: String, default: 'Nameless'}
};
```

My goal is to use this keys in a ng-repeat, so I can do something like this:

```
<p> {{ user.username.desc }}: {{ user.username.value }} </p>
```

With output: Name: Nameless

My problem is: I should be doing something wrong. I'm receiving syntax errors and my server dont even start.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set default with a function, so create one, also you can use preSave to validate your model like:

```
UserModel.pre('save', function(next) {
  var self = this;

  // validate username field here
  });
}
```

more info here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html